# Using API call in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api, ssjs

I would like to know if we can do an API call Using SSJS.
My need is to extract data from a data extension and target an end point using API call. 
The SSJS is unfortunlly not documented very well.

I do a sample just to target end point using one data but the automation fail.

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");

var url = 'https://mcmgxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var payload = "";
payload += '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id":"xx","client_secret":"vxx"}';

var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
var statusCode = result["StatusCode"];
var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;

url= "";
url = "https://mcmgxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com";
url += "/interaction/v1/events";
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

payload = "";

payload += '{';
payload += ' "ContactKey": "01010102",';
payload += ' "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-xxx",';
payload += ' "Data": {';
payload += '    "C_CustomerID": "01010102"';
payload += '   },';
payload += ' }';


try {

    result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
    result = Stringify(result).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    log.Rows.Add({"Message": "result: " + result});

} catch (e) {

    e = Stringify(e).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')
    log.Rows.Add({"Message": "error: " + e});

}

</script>
```

Comment: Try running this on a CloudPage, it will be easier to debug there, and once this script is working, move it to automation studio. And what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have this error message : error: {"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call.  See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call.  See inner exception for details.\r\n  Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Answer (score 0):

find below a valid call from the SFMC POSTman Collection found here:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman

The SubscriberKey field in the valid example contains the SAME value as ContactKey, which means: try to to align both fields in your call, where the IDs seem to differ. This inconsistency should be causing the "Bad Request".

If this alone doesn't help, try aligning more closely with the example, i.e. call the field "SubscriberKey" in your DE and try to include the Email as well as all other mandatory fields in the payload (if it is in your Entry Source DE of course).

```
 "ContactKey": "DD301",
 "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-0dbe46de-74f9-a309-7778-298c0a565f93",
 "Data": {
     "SubscriberKey": "DD301",
     "Email": "aaron.cates@salesforce.com",
     "First_Name": "Aaron",
     "Last_Name": "Cates"
 }
```

Comment: the same error occurs, I just try . I also try to debug in Cloud page, and I complete also whit the "account_id" in the first playload